# SwiftUI - Keyboard avoidance pushes content into navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view with some text fields. Selecting the top text field causes keyboard avoidance to push everything up to keep the bottom text field visible. In this case, it pushes the "Input 1" text above the top text field into the navigation bar, hiding it.

```
struct Settings: View {
    @State private var input1: String = ""
    @State private var input2: String = ""
    @State private var input3: String = ""
    @State private var input4: String = ""
    @State private var input5: String = ""
    
    init() {
        let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        coloredAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        coloredAppearance.backgroundColor = .gray

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = coloredAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                Group {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Input 1")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        TextField("", text: $input1)
                            .disableAutocorrection(true)
                            .padding()
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(.gray))
                    }
                }
                Group {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Input 2")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        TextField("", text: $input2)
                            .disableAutocorrection(true)
                            .padding()
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(.gray))
                    }
                }
                Group {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Input 3")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        TextField("", text: $input3)
                            .disableAutocorrection(true)
                            .padding()
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(.gray))
                    }
                }
                Group {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Input 4")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        TextField("", text: $input4)
                            .disableAutocorrection(true)
                            .padding()
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(.gray))
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Header", displayMode: .inline)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[Without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLqen.png)

[With keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuYYR.png)

Does anyone have a way to prevent this? I've tried spacers without success. While this might keep the text visible, it creates a space between the navigation bar and the text when the keyboard isn't open. I've also tried messing with `ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)`.

Ideally, if the top text field is selected, the keyboard should cover the bottom text fields without pushing anything up. I'd like to only push content up if necessary to keep the currently selected text field visible. Anyone have a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try wrapping your VStack in a ScrollView, and then add .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) to the Textfields

Comment: Don't ignoreSafeArea. Thats your problem you should respect the safe area (the bottom one includes your keyboard when present) with your view and all of its parents.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from a blog post from someone named [Peter Steinberger](https://steipete.com/posts/disabling-keyboard-avoidance-in-swiftui-uihostingcontroller/). Unfortunately none of the native API's fix this so you have to use some trickery to stop keyboard avoidance in SwiftUI. I've tested the code and it works! When the keyboard shows the content stays put.

```swift
        guard let viewClass = object_getClass(view) else { return }

        let viewSubclassName = String(cString: class_getName(viewClass)).appending("_IgnoresKeyboard")
        if let viewSubclass = NSClassFromString(viewSubclassName) {
            object_setClass(view, viewSubclass)
        }
        else {
            guard let viewClassNameUtf8 = (viewSubclassName as NSString).utf8String else { return }
            guard let viewSubclass = objc_allocateClassPair(viewClass, viewClassNameUtf8, 0) else { return }

            if let method = class_getInstanceMethod(viewClass, NSSelectorFromString("keyboardWillShowWithNotification:")) {
                let keyboardWillShow: @convention(block) (AnyObject, AnyObject) -> Void = { _, _ in }
                class_addMethod(viewSubclass, NSSelectorFromString("keyboardWillShowWithNotification:"),
                                imp_implementationWithBlock(keyboardWillShow), method_getTypeEncoding(method))
            }
            objc_registerClassPair(viewSubclass)
            object_setClass(view, viewSubclass)
```

Call that code within the UIHostingController subclass's initializer. I'd probably wrap it in a function within an UIHostingController extension or something.

Hope this helps!